# Snowflake - SQL compilation error: Missing column specification

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this query:

```
create table analytics.as_screenings_activity_stopped as (
select 
ka.vhost,
ka.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY, 
ka.count_units, 
min(d.go_live_date), 
s.RECORD_TYPE_NAME,
s.vplus_stage, 
s.screenings_enabled_date,
s.screenings_first_use_date,
sd.most_recent_screen_date,
case when sd.most_recent_screen_date >= dateadd(days, -90, current_date) then 'N' else 'Y' end as last_screen_90_or_more_days_ago

from analytics.key_account_yn as ka
    left join analytics.go_live_date as d on ka.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY = d.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY 
    left join analytics.screenings_enabled_first_use_date s on ka.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY = s.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY
    left join analytics.most_recent_screen_date sd on ka.vhost = sd.vhost 
where ka.key_account_yn = 'Y' and s.vplus_stage = 'Active'
group by 
ka.vhost,
ka.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY, 
ka.count_units, 
s.RECORD_TYPE_NAME,
s.vplus_stage, 
s.screenings_enabled_date,
s.screenings_first_use_date,
sd.most_recent_screen_date
order by ka.vhost);
```

It runs just fine when I don't try to create a table. I'm using the same code format as I've used with other queries. I'm getting the following error:

```
SQL compilation error: Missing column specification
```

What do I need to do to fix that? 
Thanks, 
Alissa

Answer (score 31):

Problem solved - I needed to provide an alias for min(d.go_live_date). thanks to [this](https://medium.com/@jthandy/how-compatible-are-redshift-and-snowflakes-sql-syntaxes-c2103a43ae84) article.

Updated query:

```
create table analytics.as_screenings_activity_stopped as (
select 
ka.vhost,
ka.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY, 
ka.count_units, 
min(d.go_live_date) as go_live_date, 
s.RECORD_TYPE_NAME,
s.vplus_stage, 
s.screenings_enabled_date,
s.screenings_first_use_date,
sd.most_recent_screen_date,
case when sd.most_recent_screen_date >= dateadd(days, -90, current_date) then 'N' else 'Y' end as last_screen_90_or_more_days_ago

from analytics.key_account_yn as ka
    left join analytics.go_live_date as d on ka.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY = d.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY 
    left join analytics.screenings_enabled_first_use_date s on ka.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY = s.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY
    left join analytics.most_recent_screen_date sd on ka.vhost = sd.vhost 
where ka.key_account_yn = 'Y'
group by 
ka.vhost,
ka.SFDC_ACCOUNT_KEY, 
ka.count_units, 
s.RECORD_TYPE_NAME,
s.vplus_stage, 
s.screenings_enabled_date,
s.screenings_first_use_date,
sd.most_recent_screen_date
order by ka.vhost);
```

Comment: Even a type cast expression like age::double needs to be replaced with age::double as age.

Comment: and IFNULL as well . Was in a time crunch; glad good ol' SO came through. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

while using any aggregate function, its needed to provide an alias to that aggregate in DBT